# Are Pink Brandywine and Sudduth strain tomatoes the same?

Tags: tomatoes, heirloom

The label on my packet of Pink Brandywine tomato seeds has no mention of being Sudduth strain.  Are they the same thing or should I get seeds specifically labeled as Sudduth strain to get the real thing?

Comment: I found an excellent reference here: [A History of the Brandywine Tomato by Craig LeHoullier](http://www.webgrower.com/information/craig_brandywine.html).

Comment: Interesting page.  That's a lot of variety with the Brandywine name.  Guess the ultimate test is to grow different kinds and taste them.